# java command in node.js with relative paths

Tags: java, node.js, npm-scripts

I want to run a java command in the package.json of a node.js project.

if in the correct directory in the command line I can do this:

`java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000`

But if I put this command into the script section for the package.json:

```
...
   "scripts": {
       "corenlp": "java -Xmx4g -cp \"*\" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000 "
  },...
```

I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer`

Obviously my pathing is not correct, but no matter what I do with the path I dont get it to resolve. 
Also note that this corenlp is in another directory than the node project.

```
maindir/ ---> nodeProject/package.json
         ---> cornlpServer/folder1/folder2/corenlpFiles 
                 //this is where I can run the origninal command
```

I'm not that familiar on how the java path resolver works if there is any. 
But basically I want to be able to do npm run corenlp and it behaves like the original command in the beginning. 
So how do I need to change the command so that it satisfies this behavior?

Comment: When you say "if in the correct directory" (running your java CLI), do you mean "nodeProject" or ".../corenlpFiles"?

Comment: in "../corenlpFiles"

Comment: So why would you expect it to work in your "nodeProject" dir? Have you tried a command to change the directory? Like `cd "../corenlpFiles" && java ...`

Comment: thanks that works.

Answer (score 0):

So just like @laggingreflex mentioned in the comments:
You can tell the package.json to go to the directory you want to execute the next command. 
In the mentioned Example this would be:

```
"cd ../cornlpServer/folder1/folder2/corenlpFiles 
&& java -Xmx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000"
```

Shoutouts to laggingreflex who proposed that solution.